# Isabelle theory 'Variable "return" occurs on right hand side only'

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to create my first Isabelle/HOL theory for the algorithm, that computer max integer from the two integers. My intention is to formalize algorithms, this is the initial attempt. That is why I am trying to make my Isabelle code as similar to usual s. c. "industrial programming langauges" or the algol-style code as possible. So - no much use of the default `primrec` and recursive definitions (with matching and branching) that Isabelle prefers. I came up with the theory:

```
theory Max_Of_Two_Integers
  imports Main
begin

function two_integer_max :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat"
where
  "two_integer_max first second =
     (if (first > second)  then
        return first
      else
        return second)"

end
```

But there is error message at `function` keyword:

```
Variable "return" occurs on right hand side only:
⋀first second return.
   two_integer_max first second =
   (if second < first then return first else return second)
```

I am closely following the pattern of very elaborate algorithm https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL-Imperative_HOL/Imperative_Quicksort.html and it used return as expected in usual programming.

So - what is wrong with my `return` command and how to correct it?

Besides, for this theory to be complete I have to prove termination (theorems about the nature of the function are not mandatory but I will add them).

Isabelle tutorial mainly uses `primrec` with recursive definition of functions and with pattern matching. I opted for function with the flexibility that comes with it (my guess).

Besides Tutorial, the blog post https://www.joachim-breitner.de/blog/732-Isabelle_functions__Always_total%2C_sometimes_undefined is fantastic guide to functions for Isabelle - but it is strange - it does not provide the example with `return` keyword, although - as one can see in Imperative_Quicksort example, `function` and `return` are valid constructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` is specific to writing imperative algorithms in Imperative HOL (which is what that Quicksort implementation is using). The same goes for the `do` notation. The reason why you get that error message is that you have not imported Imperative HOL.

Imperative HOL is essentially a library that allows you to write imperative programs that modify a heap. That's why the return type of `quicksort` in that example is not a list or an array, but a `unit Heap`. (But even if you had, you would still get an error message, since you are returning a `nat` and not a `Heap`).

If you're just starting out with Isabelle, I *strongly* recommend not to do anything with Imperative HOL for now. Rather, you should start with ‘normal’ Isabelle, which uses a functional style to define things. A good introduction into Isabelle is the first half of the [Concrete Semantics](http://concrete-semantics.org/) book, which is available free online.